# Avoid new line characters while generating template

Tags: python, string, templates

I'm trying to generate a test cases using Python Standard Library module **string.Template**

```
s = Template('''TestStep("0.1", "Signal match time: %d \n"
                "%s value: %d",
                SignalMatchTime,
                $QU_Signals,
                value); ''')

print(s.substitute(QU_Signals='Signal_1'))
```

The problem is, that in the output **"\n"** character is replaced a newline.

```
TestStep("0.1", "Signal match time: %d
"
                "%s value: %d",
                SignalMatchTime,
                QU_AVL_STEA_DV,
                value);
```

Required output is: (I need to save **"\n"** character in output file)

```
TestStep("0.1", "Signal match time: %d \n"
                "%s value: %d",
                SignalMatchTime,
                QU_AVL_STEA_DV,
                value);
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can avoid it?

Comment: use raw string? `r"Signal match time: %d \n"`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I used raw string at the beging of template `s = Template(r'''
testcase $QU_Signals() (...) ''' )`  and it works. Thank you!

Comment: oh yes, that works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `\n` with `\\n`

**I ran the following code:**

```
from string import Template
file = open("testfile.txt", "w")

s = Template('''TestStep("0.1", "Signal match time: %d \n"
                "%s value: %d",
                SignalMatchTime,
                $QU_Signals,
                value); ''')

file.write(s.substitute(QU_Signals='Signal_1'))
file.write("\n\n\n\n") #To add some space between the writes

s = Template('''TestStep("0.1", "Signal match time: %d \\n"
                "%s value: %d",
                SignalMatchTime,
                $QU_Signals,
                value); ''')



file.write(s.substitute(QU_Signals='Signal_1'))
```

**The result being:**

```
`TestStep("0.1", "Signal match time: %d 
"
                "%s value: %d",
                SignalMatchTime,
                Signal_1,
                value); 



TestStep("0.1", "Signal match time: %d \n"
                "%s value: %d",
                SignalMatchTime,
                Signal_1,
                value); `
```